# Hashmaps <String, integer>

Tags: java, string

Im currently working on a project in which I am using hashmaps of type . The string wont change, but is it at all possible for me to change the integer value from a method call if you catch my drift.

```
commoditiesMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
commoditiesMap.put("Steel", 10);

public void addInteger(HashMap<String, Integer> commoditiesMap)
{

}
```

Basically i need to alter the value of 10 so it can be raised or lowered when needed.

Comment: Get the current value, use it to create a new value, put the new value.

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: Refresh this page. The duplicate shows you how.

Comment: Bear in mind this is a board game. Let me re-phrase the question. I have a bank class that picks a random card each turn. Eg. "Steel is up by $2" or  "Shipping is down by $4". In a separate class called board i have the above code. Is it possible to add a value depending on what card comes up?

Comment: Yes, read the duplicate.